# How to make Virtual extended screen on windows machine?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-c++, drivers, wdk

I have to develop a windows application whose intention is to split screen in to two virtual monitors like we plug second monitor and windows detect these two monitors and provide settings according to like in this screen shot.

[image]

I have to achieve this functionality virtually simulating that a second monitor is attached. 
Please guide me how this can be achieved and what logics I should follow?

What kind of windows API I should focus on?

Do I need to interact with windows display drivers or what so ever?

This application has to be developed in C# or VB or VC++ whichever is easy to build in.

The output of this app will cause the screen to be split in two screens and should appear as two separate screens to other applications.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: You could use powershell (via shell out) - See: SupportedDisplayFeatures  (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/03/use-powershell-to-discover-multi-monitor-information.aspx)

Comment: @Anthony Horne. Thanks. But i need to develop an desktop application that simulates multiple display monitors.

Comment: So you will only have one monitor, but apps will think there are more?

Comment: yes, you got it right. :)

Comment: And screen also will be split into two parts

Comment: @Mian.Ammar did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a api to do it, but for $10 you can get an dongle that plugs in to the computer and creates a fake display. [This is the one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JKFTYA8) I used to do it and was happy with.